# replacing a value in a list of numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I need to generate two lists of arrays:
Each list will contain 1d-arrays, but lengths of each 1d-array may be different.
First list will contain some meaningful values.
Second list must be exactly the same in shape, but should contain only ones.

Code to generate first array:

```py
myarray=[]
rowcount=3
elements_per_row=[2,3,5]
for i in range (0,rowcount):
    elements=elements_per_row[i]
    temparray=np.random.randn(elements)
    myarray.append(temparray)
```

Output of the code above will be a list of arrays (namely- 3 arrays with 2,3,5 elements, filled with random numbers).

I have two questions:

1. Is there any more elegant/vectorized/computationally faster way to generate first list ( array of arrays will be fine as well)?
2. Generate a list of arrays exactly the same shape, but filled with ones:

I do understand the most straightforward way: just add one more array at the beginning, and fill it with np.ones. 
'Bruteforce' approach will be:

```py
myarray=[]
arrayofones=[]
rowcount=3
elements_per_row=[2,3,5]
for i in range (0,rowcount):
    elements=elements_per_row[i]

    #generating meaningful values
    temparray=np.random.randn(elements)
    myarray.append(temparray)

    # generating ones
    temparray=np.ones(elements)
    arrayofones.append(temparray)
```

But, what will be a better approach if `myarray` is given as an input, and I still need to get list of arrays of ones?

Comment: for the elegant way you can use: `[np.random.randn(i) for i in [2,3,5]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first array creation, you can simplify the code to:

```
import numpy as np

elements_per_row = [2, 3, 5]
myarray = [np.random.randn(elements) for elements in elements_per_row]
```

To create arrays of ones with the same shape, you can just do:

```
arrayofones = [np.ones_like(array) for array in myarray]
```

In principle there is not any more vectorized way of doing this, since NumPy arrays cannot have slices with different sizes. The closest thing would probably be using a [masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
elements_per_row = np.array([2, 3, 5])
max_elements = elements_per_row.max()
data = np.random.randn(len(elements_per_row), max_elements)
mask = np.arange(max_elements) >= elements_per_row[:, np.newaxis]
myarray = np.ma.array(data, mask=mask)
print(myarray)
# [[-1.7497654730546974 0.34268040332750216 -- -- --]
#  [0.5142188413943821 0.22117966922140045 -1.0700433305682933 -- --]
#  [-0.4580269855026243 0.43516348812289213 -0.5835950503226648
#   0.816847071685779 0.672720805709661]]
arrayofones = np.ones_like(myarray)
print(arrayofones)
# [[1.0 1.0 -- -- --]
#  [1.0 1.0 1.0 -- --]
#  [1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0]]
```

Depending on your use case, using a masked array may make things easier or more cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions:

your code:

```
import numpy as np

myarray=[]
arrayofones=[]
rowcount=3
elements_per_row=[2,3,5]
for i in range (0,rowcount):
    elements=elements_per_row[i]
    #generating meaningfull values
    temparray=np.random.randn(elements)
    myarray.append(temparray)
    # generating ones
    temparray=np.ones(elements)
    arrayofones.append(temparray)
```

```
Execution time: 40 µs ± 2.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

List comprehensions (you can give `myarray` as input):

```
elements_per_row=[2,3,5]
myarray = [np.random.randn(elements) for elements in elements_per_row]
arrayofones = [np.ones_like(a) for a in myarray]
```

```
Execution time: 29.1 µs ± 492 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```